# Sql Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-metro, sql-server-2016

Recently I've installed Microsoft Sql Server 2016 and I can't find the management studio file anyway, I wanted to know where is it located? 
Thanks

Comment: Please note that my operating system is windows 10 Enterprise x64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open the Installation Centre of SQL Server, you should see an option to install SSMS. It will direct you to a link to download.

Alternatively, you can find it here:

[SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Beginning with SQL Server 2016, SSMS is now a seperate download independent of the installation of SQL Server, You can download it and install it from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Management Studio should be available in the start menu. However, if it doesn't, please confirm if you have installed the Server, not the client. SQL Server also comes with or without Management Studio.